# FTP hosted application forbidden access error

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, ftp, http-status-code-403

We have published an application using FTP option in visual studio 2017, with a hosted url ex- https://my.base.url and I can access my api by hitting https://my.base.url/api/getMethod.
I have another api which I want to pulish and access like https://my.base.url/app2/api/getMethod and the older one will be https://my.base.url/app1/api/getMethod.
So I published code like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4bmS.png)

When I check the files via ftp://my.base.url/app1 , i could see the files deployed , but when I acccess the same using https://my.base.url/app1/api/getMethod, I am getting 403 access denied . How can I verify this and resolve.This is old web api project which having web.config and global.asax. I dont have direct access to iis , but even its something related to iis issue , How can we verify

Answer (score 0):

`Http 403` error is mainly caused by the fact that the directory browser is not enabled. Moreover, the IIS module will not be loaded correctly and thus the application request cannot be handled correctly. In order to run the web application properly, please convert the folder to application.
[image]
Besides, we could refer to URL rewrite extension to change the URL route.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks @Abraham Qian for the reply . I already did these earlier as I was hosting two apis seperately, but issue was there still. Found that some unwanted app_offline.htm file inside the folder.Removed it and now everything works as expected.